# Wrong filesystem when formatting a USB stick (linux)

Tags: linux, usb, fat32, fdisk

I used a USB stick to install a Linux distribution. Then i wanted to re-used this usb for personal data. I remove the iso signature with

```
wipefs -a /dev/sdb
```

then

```
fdisk /dev/sdb
```

I typed o to create a new empty DOS partition

I typed n to add a new partition, with the following options: primary, partition number 1, first/last sector as default

Finally I typed

```
mkdosfs -F 32 /dev/sdb1
```

However the command

```
fdisk -l /deb/sdb
```

gives

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 1,9 GiB, 2004877312 bytes, 3915776 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x674f2fa6

Device     Boot  Start  End      Sectors  Size  Id  Type 
/dev/sdb1        2048   3915775  3913728  1,9G  83  Linux
```

Why is the type Linux and not FAT 32?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *type* you observe in `fdisk` output is set in the partition table and is independent to the actual filesystem. Tools like `mkdosfs` do not touch partition table. It is a good thing, it corresponds to the Unix Philosophy where one tool should do one job and do it well. The target of `mkfs.*` may be a whole device or even a regular file; there is no partition table in these cases. The tool doesn't wander and seek partition table to update.

The *type* should match with actual filesystem on partition but it's the user's (root's, admin's) job to match them.

Invoke `fdisk /dev/sdb`, give the command `t` and follow instructions. At some point you will be able to check all available types by typing `L`. I believe you should choose `c` (or equivalent `0C`) for FAT32 partition.